# Showing error while mounting EFS to an instance in my Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

Followed the following procedure for attaching the EFS file to instances created using EB:

[https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-mount-efs-volumes/#:~:text=In%20an%20Elastic%20Beanstalk%20environment,scale%20up%20to%20multiple%20instances](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-mount-efs-volumes/#:%7E:text=In%20an%20Elastic%20Beanstalk%20environment,scale%20up%20to%20multiple%20instances).

But the logs of Elastic Beanstalk are showing following error:

```
[Instance: i-06593*****] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...fs ... mount -t efs -o tls fs-d9****:/ /efs Failed to resolve "fs-d9****.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/efs/mount-dns-name for more detail. ERROR: Mount command failed!. command 01_mount in .ebextensions/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Just used **** in EFS ID for security.

Comment: Can you login to the EB instance and manually try mounting your EFS, just to confirm that it works.

Comment: Hey sorry for such a late reply. My issue was resolved by creating the new EFS and copying all the components from previous EFS to this new EFS. There was some problem with the previous EFS that I was not able to figure out

Comment: Hi. Thanks for letting me know. If you don't mind, I would like to provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to create **new EFS filesystem**, instead of using the original one.